# Lubuntu (Ubuntu 17.10) able to start GUI only with second monitor

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, lightdm

Screenshot of my main monitor

[image: screenshot of my main monitor(laptop)]

I'm running a freshly installed Lubuntu (Ubuntu 17.10) and I'm able to start GUI only with second monitor physically connected (VGA).

**Steps:**

- login as my user
- `su` (login in to root)
- `lightdm` (and I luckily boot in GUI with two monitors displaying working)
  Then I tried to turn off the second monitor in **Display Settings -> Advanced**
- I select option `"Turn off external monitor and use only laptop LCD only"` in **Display Settings -> Quick Options**
  Then **Apply -> Save**
  next I disconnect the VGA cable
  reboot 
  and again I see the screen that I posted in the screenshot link that says `/dev/sda1: clean .... blocks`

And I need it to boot normally with one laptop monitor smoothly without entering commands in the command-line.